# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations in React Native project

Tags: react-native, babeljs, tsconfig

I'm trying to include paths aliases to my project in React Native.
In fact when I start the app it's working so I think my `babel.config.js` is ok, but in VSCode stills appear an error telling `Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations` so I think I'm having my `tsconfig.json` wrong

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        alias: {
          '@ali/assets': './src/assets',
          '@ali/components': './src/components',
          '@ali/colors': './src/theme/colors.ts'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ali/assets": ["./src/assets/*"],
      "@ali/components": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@ali/colors": ["./src/theme/colors"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Here's my file
**src/screens/Login/index.tsx**

```
import Wellcome from '@ali/components/LogIn/Wellcome'
import React from 'react'

import LoginForm from '../../components/forms/LoginForm'

export const LogIn = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Wellcome />
      <LoginForm />
    </>
  )
}

export default LogIn
```

I can see my component Wellcome in my app, but in VSCode stills appear the error.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your IDE yet? If it works at runtime that you see it working, then it's an IDE issue

Comment: Yes @tmhao2005 i've tried it. I know sometimes it get shocked and sometimes solves a lot of ide warning and errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a `tsconfig.json` bad configuration.

You should add `baseUrl` and remove the starting "." from paths routes.

Try this:

```
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
      "@ali/assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@ali/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@ali/colors/*": ["src/theme/colors"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the tsconfig options order matters, try to replace paths after noEmit and add baseUrl

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ali/assets": ["./src/assets/*"],
      "@ali/components": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@ali/colors": ["./src/theme/colors"]
    }
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

i hope this works for you